# How to open a file using a specified third party program in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

so what I'm trying to do is open a file (well, actually *two folders*, but I figure I'll start with a single file for now) using a third party comparison tool called UltraCompare. I'm working in a C# website project in Visual Studio 2010 (Express edition). I've seen how to open a file using a different program, here: [Open a file with Notepad in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055266/open-a-file-with-notepad-in-c-sharp).

Problem is, this only lets you open it using the default program for that file type. But I want to open it in a *specified* program. For example, a text file should open in UltraCompare, not notepad. Here's the code which does this:

```
string textBoxContents1 = TextBox1.Text;
Process.Start(textBoxContents1);
```

The textbox on the webform accepts a string, in which the user types the file's full path (not the most user-friendly design I know, but I'm not sure how to allow them to browse for a *folder* using a GUI interface in asp.NET). The file is then passed into the Process.Start() method, which opens it using the default program for that file type.

Is there any way to modify this to make it open using UltraCompare??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the program you want to open the file in:

```
Process.Start("yourprogram.exe", textBoxContents1);
```

**Update**

To open two files in Ultracompare, you'd probably do something like that:

```
Process.Start("yourprogram.exe", "file1.txt file2.txt");
```

Keep in mind that the second parameter of [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method are the arguments passed to the program.

I said this is probably going to work because I assumed to be very likely that Ultracompare expects 2 arguments, but this might not be the case.

Comment: oh awesome! I had tried doing this before but didn't realize you had to put the full file path of the program. I was just typing in "UltraCompare" and getting an error. But it works when I go "C:\Program Files\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraCompare\uc.exe". Thanks Adrian! :)

Comment: um actually there's a problem. UltraCompare allows you to open two files simultaneously and view them side by side. But using this Process.Start() method opens up two separate instances of UC, one for each file. Do you know if there's a way to open both files in the same window?

Comment: Yes that works! But only if I hardcode the filenames... which kind of defeats the purpose of the program if I have to manually change them with every new file. Is there a way to do this dynamically using the textBoxContents values? I tried putting them in quotes and without but neither way seemed to work :(

Comment: @user1985189 Dude, that's just an example. Assemble the string from your variables

Comment: Sorry, I'm very grateful for your helpful and prompt suggestions, but not sure what you mean by "Assemble the string from your variables". I'm very new to programming in general, let alone C#.NET! What I tried doing was Process.Start("yourprogram.exe", "textBoxContents1 textBoxContents2"); That didn't open properly, and it won't even compile if I omit the quotes.

Comment: This is waht you need: `Process.Start("yourprogram.exe", textBoxContents1 + " " + textBoxContents2)`. You were passing the names of the variables inside the string. By concatenating (which is what I just showed you), you are assembling the string with the variable contents

Answer (score 0):

Quick question: Are you trying to do this for the client machine? Hope not 
And I guess it looks into the PATH variable for finding your exe

Comment: Do you mean are the files located on my client machine? Versus on the server? Sorry I'm a coop student and not too sure what you mean...

Comment: Process.start opens up the program in server. If you are hosting the website and using it on same machine and not on other machines, it wont be a problem

Comment: Does this mean that if someone else were to run my program on their machine, that it wouldn't work? Because that would be a problem...

Comment: If it is a hosted say in Machine A and someone browses the website from Machine B, this wont work (as the Process is started in Machine A and Machine B user has no way in seeing what is happening on Machine A.  Have a look at:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204742/run-exe-on-client-system-from-server-side-c-sharp-code

Comment: Ah ok. Hmmm not sure if I'm hosting it or not. Is there a way to check or is it generally the default that the person creating the .NET project is the host? Sorry if that's a stupid question but I am a huge  noob in all this..

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve with this web application. Then only I can help you sort out